# Hash of hashes of arrays of hashes, Itunes wishlist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, hash

Cheers! Please, help me to solve the problem - I have a cookies, which is hash:

```
> cookies.keys
=> [:wishlist]
```

Then:

```
> cookies[:wishlist].keys
=> ["result_count", "results"]
```

results is an array of Hashie::rash

```
> cookies[:wishlist].results[0].keys
=> ["wrapper_type", "kind", "artist_id", ...]
```

cookies is hash, cookies[:wishlist] is Hashie::Rash, results is an array, which contains other Hashie::Rash'ies.
The question is how could I add new data to wishlist without deleting old data (add track to wishlist, for example)?

Comment: I think about using cookies.as_json.merge, it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this structure:

```
cookies = {
  :wishlist => Hashie::Rash.new({
    'resultCount' => 2,
    'results' => [
      Hashie::Rash.new({
        'wrapperType' => 'foo1',
        'kind'        => 'bar1',
        'artistId'    => 'baz1'
      }),
      Hashie::Rash.new({
        'wrapperType' => 'foo2',
        'kind'        => 'bar2',
        'artistId'    => 'baz2'
      })
    ]
  })
}
```

You can simply use `Array#push` to add new items to your `results`:

```
require 'rash'

new_wishlist_item = Hashie::Rash.new({
  'wrapperType' => 'foo3',
  'kind'        => 'bar3',
  'artistId'    => 'baz3'
})

cookies[:wishlist].results.push( new_wishlist_item )
cookies[:wishlist].result_count = results.count

cookies[:wishlist].results.each do |r|
  puts r.wrapper_type
end
```

Output:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
```

Comment: It works! Thank you, but what if I have empty ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar (no items in wishlist yet)? Any tip how to implement it in Rails's controller? Something like save action.

Comment: How do you create your wishlist normally?

Comment: I'm using ITunes gem, and I'm saving found track like this:
`@track = ITunes.music("#{params["search_query"]}")`
I need to save wishlist in cookies, 'cause I shouldn't use any DB.
So now I need to add Hashie::Rash (@track) in cookies.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my awful English.

Comment: I'm really sorry to say that, but persisting your data in cookies is an awful idea. Cookies are sent to the client, who can _optionally_ store them and _optionally_ send them back to the server on every request. This means, you can never be sure that the data won't be lost.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's totally stupid idea, but I need to do this task.

Comment: Well, i do not really understand what your problem is. You have a cookie where you store a wishlist, now you know how to add an item. If there is no wishlist, just go and create one, for example with `cookies[:wishlist] ||= #code to create wishlist here`

Comment: Oh, it's all clear now! Thank you a lot, or "spasibo" in russian.

Comment: No problem, or "Bez problémov!" in slovak ;-)